# Use polygons in bootleaf sidebar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

What do I have to edit in [bootleaf] (https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf) app.js file in order to use a polygon layer named "comuni" in the sidebar instead of "Theaters" and "Museums" ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded the polygons instead of points and Bootleaf works. But apple sidebar remain the mapicon of tearti. Also, if I click on the list in the sidebar, I do not make the pan / zoom the item ...

Comment: How did you "uploaded" polygons?

Comment: for the zooming part I got this hint from the author "To zoom to a polygon in the sidebarClick function, you will need to do something like map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());"

Comment: `$(document).one("ajaxStop", function () {
  /* Fit map to boroughs bounds */
  //map.fitBounds(theaters1.getBounds());` Her you can disable the zoom to a geometry or change to another geometri (file app.js)

Answer (score 0):

The tabs are here https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf/blob/master/index.html#L82 (and previous line)..
I assume you edited only app.js but you didn't touch index.html...

Comment: I got the html, my problem is to update the app.js so I can see "Comnuni" polygons instead of theatres

Comment: I suggest to do a search in the file for theatres, perhaps you missed something... For example here shows the icon in the layer selector https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf/blob/master/assets/js/app.js#L422

Comment: I'm way behind that... I have Comuni.geoJSON but I dunno what to edit in app.js in order to display my data and not the default